# How can I receive e-mails based on certain Windows Firewall events?

Tags: windows, email, windows-firewall, event-log

Is it possible to receive an e-mail when Windows Firewall logs certain events (such as an inbound connection being accepted for example)?

Comment: This was a question asked recently which was slightly broad since it covered all third-party firewalls as well. Instead of narrowing it down to only Windows Firewall however the questioner decided to delete it altogether, which was unfortunate. Since I had most of an answer written down already I decided to submit it instead of wasting effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security** and click *Properties* under the *Actions* pane to the right.
2. Enable connection logging for the profile (Domain/Private/Public) you want:

   [image: 1]
3. Open **Event Viewer** and navigate to `Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`.
4. Here you'll see four logs: ConnectionSecurity, ConnectionSecurityVerbose, Firewall and FirewallVerbose. To enable the logs marked "verbose", under the *Actions* pane to the right click on *Enable Log*.
5. Now wait for some events to be logged, then in *Event Viewer* select the Firewall event you're interested in and in the *Actions* pane click on *Attach Task To This Event*.
6. When you specify the *Action* for the task you can choose to *Send an E-mail*:

   [image: 2]
7. If you additionally want the full event details then create a simple batch file that uses *wevtutil* to filter the appropriate log based on the *EventID*, like so:

   ```
   wevtutil qe System "/q:*[System [(EventID=20274)]]" /f:text /rd:true /c:1 > D:\Attach.txt
   ```
8. Finally, open **Task Scheduler**, locate your task under `Task Scheduler Library\Event Viewer Tasks` and modify it to include an additional action to run the batch file before sending out the e-mail. Also modify the e-mail action to include the text file created by *wevtutil* as an attachment:

   [image: 3]

Additional reading: [Customize Logging Settings for a Firewall Profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd448556.aspx). Also see [this article](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/jmassardo/archive/2011/05/26/event-log-triggers.aspx) if you're interested in e-mailing event details without running a separate batch file (basically by editing the XML of the scheduled task and adding XPath queries to retrieve event data).

Moreover, keep in mind that Task Scheduler doesn't support SMTP authentication, which is dumb. This means if you're using your ISP's or Microsoft/Google/Yahoo's SMTP server for example you're out of luck unless you use either [PowerShell](http://www.howtogeek.com/120011/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-send-email-from-the-command-line-in-windows-without-extra-software/) or a third-party e-mail program such as [Blat](http://www.blat.net) or [SendEmail](http://www.howtogeek.com/125045/how-to-easily-send-emails-from-the-windows-task-scheduler/). Just remember to create a *Start a program* action instead of a *Send an e-mail* one in this case.